# Firefox add on sdk - how to find which subrequest is related to which main request or top level request

Tags: firefox, sdk, mozilla

Firefox add on sdk - how to find which subrequest is related to which main request or top level request.

```
var httpRequestObserver =   {
          observe: function(subject, topic, data)
          {
            if (topic == "http-on-modify-request")
            {

                var httpChannel     = subject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);

                console.log("current URI: " + httpChannel.URI.spec+"\n");//i know uri.spec gives me all intercepeted request but i wanted to know these subrequest are from which domain.


            }

}
```

I need to find out forexample http://ww.sitepoint.com i typed in browser and than in firebug you can see all subrequest, how they are mapped to top level url.

kind of :

```
sitepoint.com
{
  'req1':abcd
}
```

etc.